# Matlab Sorting String Calendar Dates

Tags: matlab, sorting, calendar, plot, string-comparison

I have data in the following format

MovieID, CalendarWeek, Popularity

10006, 52-01, 5  
10006, 1-02, 4 
10006, 2-02, 9 
10006, ....... 
10006, 52-05 10 
............... 
20032, 14-03, 6 
............... 
20032, 51-05, 9 
30023, 34-04, 8 
30023, 35-04, 10 
...............

Hence , every movie has data starting from different calendar weeks. I want to plot Popularity with respect to Calendar Week for each movie.
The steps I did are as follows:
1- Get unique movie Ids from the above data
2- For each unique movieId, plot Popularity w.r.t length (CalendarWeek ). Hold all plots on one figure.
This is wrong approach as it doesnot plot according to correct calendar week. Secondly I am not able to label CalendarWeek on x-axis.

Please guide .

Comment: I think you need to separate the string using regular expressions. After this it is not hard to apply the sort function.

Comment: Dennis, i import my data using the following commands: filename='movieDataSet2001_02_03.txt'; fid=fopen(filename); input=textscan(fid,'%d %s %d','delimiter',',');   i can't apply sort on the basis of CalendarWeek as it does wierd String sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you parse your data? Did you get the CalendarWeek column as a string? Did you use any of the Matlab date functions?
Because loading the data as you describe them will only cause Matlab to make a subtraction 52-01 = 51

Comment: filename='movieDataSet2001_02_03.txt';
fid=fopen(filename);
input=textscan(fid,'%d  %s %d','delimiter',',');

Comment: Yes , i import Calendar Week as string in matlab. and if i try to sort on that string- it gives wierd result as 1-01, 11-01,..1-02,11-02... 1-03,11-03 eTc.

Comment: if you run this `[week,year] = strread('52-01','%d%d','delimiter','-')` you can split the string and then sort first using the `year` and then the `week`

Comment: What is your problem with labeling? Right after the `plot(...)` function you type `xlabel('Calendar Week')`. You need something different?

Comment: No i need to label Calendar week, but i was confused about sorting on Calendar Week. So, for now consider i have 50 movies in data set and i extract it as [MovieID CalendarWeek Popularity] FROM my file. Then I sort my data on the basis of Calendar Week. Then i extract each movies data - and then how i plot? this is confusing. coz each movie has different calendarweek data.

Comment: I get your problem. One solution would be to create an extra matrix using all the weeks from the earliest to the latest in your data set. First column could be `repmat([1:52],[yearStart:yearEnd])'` and second column something like
`k=1;
for y = yearStart:yearEnd
years(:,k)= ones(52,1)*y;
k=k+1;
end
years=years(:);`

Comment: You can use this to create a sum for example 2005+31 (so that the "index" matrix you created has one row or column) and then use the same sum in your dataset and plot according to this. the distance will be correct.